# How to check the files are present or not after sent those in a destination directory using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have created a test plan using JMeter in which I have just moved the files from source folder to destination folder and in that, I have successfully succeeded.

**Now the main problem is after moving files from source to the destination folder, The files are automatically deleted by the server after 5 or 6 seconds where I have sent the files. That's the functionality of the internal server. I just have to check the files that I have sent are present or not in the destination folder before the files get deleted by the server and also want to measures the time after how much time the files will be deleted from the destination folder.**

How can I do this, Can Anyone please help me with this?

> My Test Plan is:

[image]

> Example: values Inputs

```
source = /home/example/sourcefile.csv
destination = /main/destination/destinationFOlder/destinationFile.csv
```

Comment: Whether file can be accessed using public url?. For example, file is in the path `/img/home.jpg` in your server and it should be accessible by link `your_base_url/img/home.jpg`

Comment: I don't know about how the functioning is happening on the server-side.  My requirement is just to check the files are moved to the destination folder or not before it gets deleted by the server.

Comment: Sorry i am still not clear. Where you are running your Jmeter test if it is in server you can use this script since you can access your server directories but your testing it from your local machine and you cannot access the directories in the server so you need to access the file from the server using its external link

Comment: I have run my JMeter script on the server using putty. I have updated my question with an example for more clarification. Please see that also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running JMeter at the same machine (server) - just call [File.exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) function which returns `true` if the file is present and `false` otherwise

[image]

also don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts like `{destination}`, use `vars.get('destination')` expression instead where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance.

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Actually, `destination` comes from the CSV config data set. So, Is it okay to use `vars.get('destination')` instead of `${destination}`?

Comment: And, I want to run the script until the file gets deleted by the server automatically. I want to measure the time when the file gets deleted by the server from the destination folder after sent to the destination folder. How can I do this? Please let me know?

Comment: There's no good way to measure file existence time (you'd basically need to write a loop and keep polling till the file disappears).  You're likely better off checking for a downstream artifact of processing.